# PowerShell functions and performance

Tags: powershell

I've been wondering about the performance impact of functions in PowerShell.
Let's say we want to generate 100.000 random numbers using System.Random.

```
$ranGen = New-Object System.Random
```

Executing

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 100000; $i++) {
    $void = $ranGen.Next()
}
```

finishes within 0.19 seconds.
I put the call inside a function

```
Get-RandomNumber {
    param( $ranGen )

    $ranGen.Next()
}
```

Executing

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 100000; $i++) {
    $void = Get-RandomNumber $ranGen
}
```

takes about 4 seconds.

Why is there such a huge performance impact?

Is there a way I can use functions and still get the performance I have with the direct call?

Are there better (more performant) ways of code encapsulation in PowerShell?

Comment: I tried make function with strict input and output types (i.e. specify input parameter type as `System.Random` and output type as `int`). But this just added another second. (

Comment: if you don't pass `$ranGen` as a parameter, but use it directly, it saves a second. and if define `$global:ranGen` and use this global var in the function, it saves another second.

Comment: I see no difference when I specify the parameter types. If I call $ranGen directly (or as a global variable), the code takes one second more. Weird.

Comment: As an aside: You can speed up the loop by replacing `for ($i=0; $i -lt 100000; $i++)` with `foreach ($i in 1..100000)` - perhaps surprisingly, creating an array of indices first, using the [range operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-) (`..`) , and looping over the array's elements with [`foreach`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) is faster  than a functionally equivalent `for` loop (albeit more memory-intensive, though that will rarely matter).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

a function call is *expensive*. The way to get around that is to put as much as you can IN the function. take a look at the following ...

```
$ranGen = New-Object System.Random
$RepeatCount = 1e4

'Basic for loop = {0}' -f (Measure-Command -Expression {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $RepeatCount; $i++) {
        $Null = $ranGen.Next()
    }
    }).TotalMilliseconds

'Core in function = {0}' -f (Measure-Command -Expression {
function Get-RandNum_Core {
    param ($ranGen)
    $ranGen.Next()
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $RepeatCount; $i++) {
        $Null = Get-RandNum_Core $ranGen
    }
    }).TotalMilliseconds

'All in function = {0}' -f (Measure-Command -Expression {
    function Get-RandNum_All {
        param ($ranGen)
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $RepeatCount; $i++) {
            $Null = $ranGen.Next()
            }
        }
    Get-RandNum_All $ranGen
    }).TotalMilliseconds
```

output ...

```
Basic for loop = 49.4918
Core in function = 701.5473
All in function = 19.5579
```

from what i vaguely recall [and can't find again], after a certain number of repeats, the <strike>function</strike> scriptblock gets JIT-ed ... that seems to be where the speed comes from.

Comment: Wow! Get-RanNum_All is a major performance improvement! Thanks, I didn't know that! I thought PowerShell was always JIT-ed.

Comment: @Ben - yep, it seems to be JIT-ed only when it gets repeated "often enuf" ... whatever that may be. [*grin*]

Comment: 16 times, according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202462/does-powershell-compile-scripts

Comment: @JanneTuukkanen - _thank you_! that is exactly the sort of info i was seeking ... [*grin*]

Comment: See: [`#19322` Optimize static code reusage](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/discussions/19322)