# Compiling PowerShell into a DLL?

Tags: powershell, dll

Is it possible to compile PowerShell code into a .dll file? After all, it's a .NET language just like C# or VB.net.

Comment: No, PowerShell is a interpreted language not a compiled one. If you want a compiled cmdlet, do it in C#.

Comment: Is the goal to obfuscate the source code? Why is there an interest in compilation?

Comment: You can wrap a script in a dll if you use system.management.automation and create a Powershell object in it, add a script and invoke it, but it makes no sense at all to do something like that (I really can't think of a valid use case to do that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34236617/45375), from a key PowerShell team member involved in implementing the *dynamic, transient, behind-the-scenes compilation* present since PowerShell v3, has detailed background information.

In short:

- No, PowerShell code cannot be compiled directly into a .NET assembly.
- Even if this *were* to be implemented, which is *technically* possible:

  - The resulting assembly would still depend on a PowerShell runtime.
  - "It would be somewhat *difficult and awkward to call PowerShell scripts from other languages* because several factors - primarily pipelining and parameter binding - *differ somewhat from normal method dispatch*." (emphasis added)
  - I take from that: This isn't worth implementing.
- As [bluuf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4910940/bluuf) notes, you can write a compiled *wrapper*, such as in C#, around PowerShell code, via the [PowerShell SDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/windows-powershell-host-quickstart):

  - However, doing so is only worthwhile for selective calls to PowerShell cmdlets in order to benefit from their high-level functionality.
  - In other words: such a wrapper would (should) still mostly consist of code in the language that the wrapper is written in, such as C#.